# Max memory for HHVM instance on vServer

Tags: nginx, php, memory, hhvm

Im tried hhvm on my vServer and have problems with the memory used. The performance is great, but the used memory consumption is horrible. I have a vServer with min 4GB and max 8GB memory and hhvm uses after 1 day about 2.4GB of the available memory - but still rising.

Is there a option in server.ini to set the max memory which should be used for the hhvm process?

I'm currently running Typo3 and Prestashop inside hhvm

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
}
```

and server.ini

```
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

; hhvm specific

;hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.file_socket = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
```

Comment: Very keen on knowing this as well. I am running a number of WordPress installs on top of HHVM, and have basically had to resort to configuring Monit to watch and restart HHVM since it crashes for lack of memory at least 2-3 times a day.